# using fputcsv is only returning one row of data to export

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv, fputcsv

I have some code here that exports to a csv file. I connected to the database and saw that there was well over 30 entries or so. But I'm only getting one in the csv file. The top part gets the headings for the file and the bottom the values, the values array is only returning one array and putting it into the file. I'm not sure what's causing this issue. Anny suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
$FileName = "mro_export_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time()).".csv";
$file = fopen($FileName,"w");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$table` LIMIT 11");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
// Save headings alon
$HeadingsArray=array();
foreach($row as $name => $value){
    $HeadingsArray[]=$name;
}
fputcsv($file,$HeadingsArray);
$ValuesArray=array();
foreach($row as $name => $value){
    $ValuesArray[]=$value;
}
fputcsv($file,$ValuesArray);
fclose($file);

header("Location: $FileName");
?>
```

Comment: You're only calling `mysql_fetch_assoc()` once, so you only get one row from the DB.

Comment: FYI, your two `foreach` loops are equivalent to `$HeadingsArray = array_keys($row)` and `$ValuesArray = array_values($row)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `mysql_fetch_assoc` in a loop to get all the rows.

```
<?php
$FileName = "mro_export_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time()).".csv";
$file = fopen($FileName,"w");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$table` LIMIT 11") or die(mysql_error());
$first_line = true;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    if ($first_line) {
        // Save headings alon
        fputcsv($file, array_keys($row));
        $first_line = false;
    }
    fputcsv($file, array_values($row));
}
fclose($file);

header("Location: $FileName");
?>
```